# Deletar uma determinada linha de um .csv usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que quando o usuário digitasse o nome de uma pessoa que estivesse dentro do arquivo .csv, a linha dele e as linhas de filmes que ele avaliou fossem apagadas (usei um identificador pra isso), o código é esse:

```
import csv

with open("arquivo.csv", "r") as arq:
linhas = csv.reader(arq, delimiter=";")
critico = input("Digite o nome do crítico que você deseja deletar..: ").capitalize()
for linha in linhas:
    tipo, identificador, nome, nota = linha
    if tipo == "C":
        if critico in linha:
            ident = linha[1]
            print(linha)

    if tipo == "F" and identificador == ident:
        print(linha)
```

e estou usando esses dados salvo em .csv para ler:

```
C;1;Kenneth;kennethsousabr@gmail.com
F;1;Matrix;5.0
F;1;Mad Max;4.5
C;2;Josue;josuegordao@hotmail.com
F;2;Miss Sunshine;4.2
C;3;Maria;mariacarla@uol.com
F;3;Amelie Poulain;3.0
F;3;Drive;2.0
```

O que fazer para deletar as linhas de um crítico?

**EDIT:** Pequeno erro ao excluir os arquivos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pergunta: se você buscará pelo nome do crítico, não bastaria você comparar `critico == nome` ao invés de fazer `critico in linha`? E quando localizado o crítico, é armazenado em `ident` o valor de `identificador` e todas as linhas que possuírem esse identificador deverão ser removidas?

Comment: Sim, vendo aqui você está correto, é que eu soube sobre esse método de colocar variáveis pra cada coluna agora.
Quando localizado o crítico todas as linhas com esse identificador devem ser removidas, então sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar a necessidade de trabalhar com arquivos temporários, você deverá armazenar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória e escrevê-lo conforme a necessidade. Para fazer isso, lemos o arquivo inteiro:

```
# Abre o arquivo para a leitura:
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:

    # Analisa o arquivo como CSV:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')

    # Armazena o conteúdo do arquivo em memória:
    data = list(reader)
```

Assim, o objeto `data` será uma lista com todas as linhas do arquivo. Para a escrita, então, abrimos o arquivo no modo `w` e percorremos as linhas em `data`, fazendo a verificação:

```
# Abre o arquivo para escrita:
with open("data.csv", "w") as file:

    # Cria o objeto de escrita CSV:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')

    # Identificador do crítico:
    ident = None

    # Percorre as linhas do arquivo:
    for line in data:

        # Extrai os dados da linha:
        tipo, identificador, nome, nota = line

        # Verifica se a linha corresponde ao crítico:
        if tipo == 'C' and nome == critico:

            # Sim, então define o identificador:
            ident = identificador

        # Verifica se a linha não é uma avaliação do crítico:
        if identificador != ident:

            # Sim, então mantém a linha no arquivo:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/KBus/3).

Comment: Funcionou, mas quando eu rodo no Pycharm ou Atom o arquivo csv após executar o código ele fica com um espaço em branco entre as linhas, fazendo assim com que dê erro de "not enough values".
Ex: Eu excluo Kenneth e todos os filmes relacionado a ele, depois de excluído o arquivo coloca um espaço em branco em cada linha. Existe algum método para imprimir sem esses espaços em branco?
OBS: Imagem do arquivo atualizado acima.

Comment: @KennethAnderson arrumado.

Comment: Com um newline=" " ao abrir o arquivo também funciona, acabei de testar.

Answer (score 2):

Leia o arquivo para uma lista, assim:

```
with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
   linhas = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
   lst = list(linhas)
```

De um print na lista para ver seu conteúdo:

```
print (lst)
```

Em seguida remova o elemento que vc deseja através do seu valor, algo como:

```
 lst.remove([F,1,Matrix,5.0])
```

Salve a lista (sem os removidos) sobrepondo o arquivo original:

```
with open('csv1.csv', 'w') as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writer(lst)
```