# Apagar determinadas linhas de um .csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual seria a maneira mais fácil de excluir apenas determinadas linhas do arquivo .csv dentro de várias outras?

No .csv abaixo eu gostaria que apenas as linhas do **Cliente** (C) Cleiton e seus **filmes** (F) que no caso seriam **Cidade de Deus e Crepusculo** fossem excluídas.

```
    C;7;Josue;josuezim@hotmail.com
    F;Matrix ;3.5
    F;Avengers;3.1
    C;8;Cleiton;cleitinhorasta@hotmail.com
    F;Cidade de Deus;5.0
    F;Crepusculo;3.2
    C;9;Roberta;robertalopes@uol.com.br
    F;Avengers;4.5
    C;10;Romulo;romulobarros@gmail.com
    F;Matrix;4.9
    F;Drive;4.0
    F;Tropa de Elite;3.5
```

Depois disso eu pegaria os dados de todos os outros clientes e sobrescreveria no arquivo. Eu até agora cheguei a essa parte do código:

```
import csv

contador = 0
with open("arquivo.csv", "w") as arq:
    reader = csv.reader(arq, delimiter=';')
    data = list(reader)

critico = input("-> ")
with open("arquivo.csv", "r",) as arq:
    writer = csv.writer(arq, delimiter=';')
    ident = None
    for line in data:
        if line[0] == 'C' and line[1] == critico:
            identificador = int(line[1])

            if line[0] == 'F':
                contador += 1
```

O código não está completo ainda, mas o que estou pensando é em primeiro apagar o arquivo com o comando **'w'** e depois sobrescrever com todos os clientes e filmes que não sejam o de algum usuário que eu escolher (no caso o cleiton).

Meu problema está em saber quantos Filmes (F) determinado usuário avaliou, já que um usuário pode avaliar quantos filmes quiser (1,2,3,4....), como calcular quantos filmes um usuário registrou?

Comment: [Respondida aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227911/7412)

Answer (score 0):

A idéia de como apagar linhas de arquivo CSV em si é mais ou menos fácil de entender - mas você usou seu arquivo CSV de uma forma tão diferente da forma mais adequada de uso do mesmo, que - pelo menos eu - passei pela pergunta umas duas vezes sem responder só de pensar na trabalheira que é tentar explicar a forma mais adequada.

Mas vamos lá: 
Primeiro - sua ideia está certa: não há como se "modificar um arquivo existente": sempre é necessário criar um novo arquivo e gravar todo o conteúdo desejado para o arquivo. Claro que em geral é melhor fazer isso em 3 etapas: (1) abrir o arquivo antigo; (2) gravar os novos dados em um arquivo com um nome diferente; (3) por fim, remover o arquivo original, e renomear o novo arquivo para tomar seu lugar. Esses 3 passos simples evitam que se o seu programa parar no meio por um erro de qualquer natureza, os seus dados sejam perdidos -  a qualquer momento você tem ou o arquivo original, ou o novo arquivo já completo.

A partir daí começam as coisas peculiares desse seus arquivos: o normalpara mum arquivo CSV é que ele seja uma única tabela, com todas as linhas tendo a mesma estrutura. Nesse caso, você criou dois tipos de linhas diferentes, significando coisas diferentes - o mais simples, para manter os dados em CSV nesse caso, é manter todos os dados em cada linha (ou seja: desnormalizados).

Mas também a pensar: será que colocar mais funcionalidades em cima de uma estrutura CSV vai resolver seu problema? Se você quer associar objetos do tipo "crítico" com objetos do tipo "filme", você tem um relacionamento -  de repente um banco de dados relacional é o melhor pra você aí.

Se esse arquivo nunca for ficar grande em comparação com a memória do computador que vai rodar (pense que um PC moderno tem cerca de 2GB de memória, e a Biblia inteira em texto ocupa cerca de 3MB - ou seja, se você tiver o equivalente à Biblia (~1000 páginas em letra pequena) de dados textuais, vai estar ocupando cerca de 0.2% da memória do computador: o que singifica que muito provavelmente você pode ter um programa que trabalha o tempo todo com todos os dados em memória, e só "salve" o conteúdo quando for conveniente.  Nesse caso, você tem que salvar num formato que possa ser lido de volta em outra execução do programa: tanto pode ser um CSV não convencional, como o que você tem, ou, pode ser um arquivo serializado como "JSON": uma sintaxe parecida com os dicionários que usamos no Python, que pode ser lida e escrita diretamente num editor de textos, mas que tem duasa vantagens nesse caso: todos os dados podem ser lidos do arquivo, ou escritos para ele, em uma única chamada de função, e, mais importante: num arquivo JSON você pode preservar a estrutura hierárquica das suas informações - e aproveitar para usar a mesma estrutura em memória.

Vamos trabalhar com essa representação dos seus dados em uma lista de dicionários na memória: isso vai permitir que você tenha um programa que faça mais operaçẽos com seus objetos - e, para me manter no assunto da questão, vou colocar funções para ler o seu arquivo CSV atual para essa estrutura, e salvar dessa estrutura pra um formato como o que você tem:

```
import csv
import json
import sys


def le_dados_csv(nome_do_arquivo):
    dados = []
    with open(nome_do_arquivo) as arq:
        leitor = csv.reader(arq, delimiter=";")
        critico = None
        for linha in leitor:
            if linha[0] == "C": # Dados de um novo crítico
                critico = {}
                critico["codigo"] = linha[1]
                critico["nome"] = linha[2]
                critico["email"] = linha[3]
                critico["filmes"] = []
                dados.append(critico)
            else: # A informação nesta linha é sobre um filme do último crítico
                filme = {}
                filme["titulo"] = linha[1]
                filme["nota"] = float(linha[2])
                # acrescenta as ifnormações sobre este filme a
                # lista de filmes do último crítico
                critico["filmes"].append(filme)
    return dados


def grava_dados_csv(nome_do_arquivo, dados):
    with open(nome_do_arquivo, "wt") as arq:
        escritor = csv.writer(arq, delimiter=";")

        for critico in dados:
            escritor.writerow(("C", critico["codigo"], critico["nome"], critico["email"]))
            for filme in critico["filmes"]:
                escritor.writerow(("F", filme["titulo"], "{:.01f}".format(filme["nota"])))



def grava_dados_json(nome_do_arquivo, dados):
    """Grava os dados do programa como uma estrutura json"""
    with open(nome_do_arquivo, "wt") as arq:
        json.dump(dados, arq, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))


def le_dados_json(nome_do_arquivo):
    """Grava os dados do programa como uma estrutura json"""
    with open(nome_do_arquivo) as arq:
        dados = json.load(arq)
    return dados


def remove_critico(dados, nome_critico):
    for indice, critico in enumerate(dados):
        if critico["nome"] == nome_critico:
            del dados[indice]
            break
    else:
        # A clausula else de um "for" em Python é executada se o "for"
        # terminou sem ser por causa de um comando "break".
        print("Critico {} não encontrado".format(nome_critico), file=sys.stderr)


# E por fim, uma função "principal" que faz o que você descreve
# na pergunta  - acreido que fica fácil você ampliar seu programa
# a partir daqui:
def principal():
    dados = le_dados_csv("arquivo.csv")
    remove_critico("Cleiton")
    grava_dados_csv("arquivo.csv")


# Executar a função principal apenas se este arquivo Python
# for executado como programa principal.
# Isso permite que outros rquivos .py possam importar
# este arquivo e usar as funções de leitura e escrita
# normalmente

if __name__ == "__main__":
    principal()
```